# MySQL busqueda de un valor en varios campos de unta tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente script para realizar busqueda de un valor en varios campos de una misma tabla en mysql, no logro que funcione.

```
mysql_select_db($database_conn_petradb, $conn_petradb);
$query_rs_buscargral = sprintf("
     SELECT *
     FROM tablanoia
     WHERE
      CONCAT ( idalta, ' ', idnoia, ' ', nombresi, ' ', subproc, ' ', estatus, ' ', reg)
      LIKE %s
     ORDER BY nombresi ASC",
GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_rs_buscargral . "%", "text")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el valor de alguna de las columnas es NULL el resultado de CONCAT es NULL. Tal vez necesites hacer:

```
concat( ifnull(idalta,''), ' ', ifnull(idnoia,''), ...)
```

ó

```
concat_ws(' ', idalta, idnoia, nombresi, subproc, estatus, reg)
```

Comment: Hola Gracias por tu ayuda, trate de agregarlo a mi codigo pero me manda un error seguro que estoy haciendo mal la sintaxis, podrias ayudarme enviando el ejemplo completo.  te lo agradezco SAL.. saludos cordiales..